# Mockito: method's return value depends on other method called

Tags: java, junit, mockito

In my unit test I need to mock an interface which among different methods has `nextItem()` and `isEmpty()` methods:

```
public interface MyQueue {
    Item nextItem();
    boolean isEmpty();
    //other methods
    ...
}
```

My requirement for the mock is that `isEmpty()` initially should return false, but after `nextItem()` was called `isEmpty()` should return true. Thus I'm mocking a queue with one item.

1. What is the simplest way to implement this kind of mock with mockito?
2. Can I implement additional requirement: calling `nextItem()` second, third time and so on will result in a specific kind of exception?

P.S. I don't want to provide the full implementation of my interface for the test, because of other methods in it, resulting in hard-to-understand and verbose code.

Comment: You can have a boolean variable that you can toggle to true when you enter nextItem()

Comment: @RohitJain can you suggest the implementation which is not verbose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve that with thenAnswer(), a feature Mockito documentation sees as controversial:

Yet another controversial feature which was not included in Mockito originally. We recommend using simple stubbing with toReturn() or toThrow() only. Those two should be just enough to test/test-drive any clean & simple code.

Here's thenAnswer:

```
private boolean called = false;

when(mock.nextItem()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
 Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {   
     called = true;       
     return item;
 }
when(mock.isEmpty()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
 Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {          
     return called;
 }
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, so far it is best solution for my problem - brief and easy to read code. I have to note that in my implementation of your idea Answers return specific types (Item and Boolean instead of Object). One minor issue with this approach - we have to introduce test class field `called`, which is only used in one test method. We can't put declaration of `called` inside test method because it then needs to be final.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example:

```
//given
MyQueue mock = mock(MyQueue.class);

given(mock.isEmpty()).willReturn(false, true);
given(mock.nextItem()).willReturn(someItem);

//when
mock.isEmpty();   //yields false
mock.nextItem();  //yields someItem
mock.isEmpty();   //yields true

//then
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mock);
inOrder.verify(mock).isEmpty();
inOrder.verify(mock).nextItem();
inOrder.verify(mock).isEmpty();
```

`willReturn(false, true)` means: *return `false` on first invocation and `true` on second*. `InOrder` object is used to verify invocation order. Change the order or remove `nextItem()` call and the test will fail.

Alternatively you can use this syntax:

```
given(mock.isEmpty()).
        willReturn(false).
        willReturn(true).
        willThrow(SpecialException.class);
```

If you need even stronger mocking semantics, you can introduce heavy artillery - custom answer callback:

```
given(mock.isEmpty()).willAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
    private int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        switch(++counter) {
            case 1: return false;
            case 2: return true;
            default: throw new SpecialException();
        }
    }
});
```

But this can easily lead to unmaintainable test code, use with caution.

Finally you can [spy your real object](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) by mocking only selected methods.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation. But your solution imposes more strict requirements on the mock: you require that `isEmpty()` will not be called more than once before `nextItem()` is called.

Comment: sadly, even heavy artillery doesn't force interaction between methods - requirements are imposed separately on each method and are based only on a number of invocations...

Comment: see my solution below, but the heavy artillery can enforce this sort of thing if you use an Answer which depends on another Answer.  It can then make decisions based on other things which may or may not have been invoked before it.

Comment: @pavel_kazlou: well, you can use the same answer object for both methods. Also you can have to answer objects sharing some global state. But this becomes to ugly to paste here...

Comment: Note that if you prefer not to use the BDDMockito methods, you can write this as `when(mock.isEmpty()).thenReturn(false, true);`.  Also note that the third and any subsequent invocations of `isEmpty()` will also return `true` - when you list multiple return values after `thenReturn` or `willReturn`, the last value that you list may be returned repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide some custom Answer implementations one of which depends on the other:

```
public class NextItemAnswer implements Answer<Item> {
   private int invocationCount = 0;
   private Item item;
   public NextItemAnswer(Item item) {
       this.item = item;
   }

   public Item answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
       invocationCount++;
       return item;
   }

   public int getInvocationCount() {
       return invocationCount;
   }
}

public class IsEmptyAnswer implements Answer<Boolean> {
   private NextItemAnswer nextItemAnswer;
   public IsEmptyAnswer(NextItemAnswer nextItemAnswer) {
       this.nextItemAnswer = nextItemAnswer;
   }
   public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
       return nextItemAnswer.getInvocationCount() >= 0;
   }
}
```

and then use it:

```
NextItemAnswer nextItemAnswer = new NextItemAnswer(item);
IsEmptyAnswer isEmptyAnswer = new IsEmptyAnswer(nextItemAnswer);

when(mock.isEmpty()).thenAnswer(isEmptyAnswer);
when(mock.nextItem()).thenAnswer(nextItemAnswer);
```

You might to tweak as i haven't tested this code, but the approach should be what you need.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see this can be actually done with Answers in a classic java style. So sad it is verbose, hiding my initial idea behind many lines of code.

Comment: you can make it slightly less verbose by using anonymous classes instead of declared ones, but the idea is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

I do realize that you explicitly wrote that you don't want to provide a full implementation of MyQueue, but, to be honest, that'd be the first thing I'd do.

In fact, I regularly provide 'mock' implementations of reasonably complex interfaces/objects for the purpose of making tests easier to test. I'm not the only one to think that: Spring Framework provides lots of mocked versions of complex objects (MockHttpServletRequest, MockHttpServletResponse, etc.), for example.

In that case, I'd avoid cluttering my test and provide this class either in a separate package or even in the production code.

A MockQueue would make your tests a lot more readable than the other (however correct) responses given here suggest.

Comment: Indeed, this is the best answer. The others are not wrong, but they failed to realize that what the user needs is just a partial implementation of the interface, with trivial logic. In JMockit, there is an API suitable for such cases: `MyQueue mock = new MockUp<MyQueue>() { boolean nextItemCalled; @Mock boolean isEmpty() { return nextItemCalled; }  @Mock Item nextItem() { nextItemCalled = true; return someItem; } }.getMockInstance();`

Comment: What if the implementation has to be changed for different tests? You then have to introduce some OO design with inheritance or composition for the implementations. I think approach with mocking only the methods I need for each test keeps unit tests simple and easy to understand. I establish the contract to which my tested class should conform, the code which is not related should be avoided. By the way, thanks for this kind of answer which involves discussion of the concept, I'm really interested in your suggestion but currently can't understand the benefits.

Comment: Well, would you mock the `Collection` interface? I've seen some people do it, but that does not sound like a good idea to me. An interface called `Queue` gives some basic assumptions to the clients of the interface. Even if the implementations might differ, the general behaviour should be more-or-less the same from the point of the view of the client classes. Do you have a more specific example of a situation where that wouldn't work?

Comment: @Eric mocking Collection is not a good idea, because there are lots of **well-tested** implementations for it, which I can reliably use to form the requirements. The opposite situation is when I need to use **my own** class/interface as dependency for tested class. If I use my own full implementations in test, well that means that I'm not testing target class in isolation, but together with Queue dependency. This means that a successful test can be broken or (which is worse) failed test can be fixed by altering the code not in tested class but in its dependency.

Comment: When using your own implementations, you have two options: either you provide a "too simple to break" implementation just for your tests (that's basically MockQueue), and testing it should not really be necessary. Or, you just reuse an actual, valid & tested, implementation. I actually have exactly that sort of objects in my current project. A DataHistory class, fairly complex and hence thoroughly tested, which I reuse in my other tests. I think it works because its behaviour is reasonably simple to understand (add things, return them in a certain order), much like a Collection, really.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your point and the examples you mentioned. I was initially looking for a mock framework approach because of the presence of other tests in the test class, that were not requiring any activity from the queue dependency. So I ended up with plain mocks supplied. And when it was time for some behavior on Queue side, I decided to use mock to keep consistency among tests. I'll keep this solution for now, but I agree with you that simple implementation of obvious interface is better than complex mock constructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell mockito to answer differently on successive calls to the same mocked method using the techniques described in [the mockito docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10).

```
when(mock.isEmpty())
  .thenReturn(false)
  .thenReturn(true);
```

will make the `isEmpty()` call return true only on the first call, and

```
when(mock.nextItem())
  .thenReturn(item)
  .thenThrow(new NextOnEmptyQueueException())
```

will make `nextItem()` return something on the first call and throw an exception on later calls.

I don't know that it's possible to make the result of one of these methods depend on sequencing of calls to the other though.  If it is indeed possible, I'm sure it's a great deal more complex.

Comment: Thanks (especially for nice chaining solution for my second question). But the same issue as with Tomasz solution remains - your solution implies that `isEmpty()` is called only once before `nextItem()` is called.

Comment: Yes, it does, but as noted in the answer I'm not sure it's possible to do better.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a utility method and then use it wherever you want.

```
public static boolean mockHasInvocation(Object mock, String methodName, Object... args) {
    return mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations().stream()
            .anyMatch(o -> o.getMethod().getName().equals(methodName) && Arrays.equals(o.getArguments(), args));
}
```

Simple usage:

```
if(mockHasInvocation(mockObject, "methodName", "argument1", "argument2")){doSomething();}
```

In this case you don't need any additional variables and it's more "Mockito style".